# Ĉu "pove" estas vorto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ŝajnas a mi, ke "pove", de "povas", ne estas vorto, laŭ La Plena, sed mi pensus, ke "pove" signifus ion similan kiel "eble" aŭ "kapable." Kion vi pensas?

Feel free to correct my Esperanto!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ENGLISH:

In Esperanto one is free to make one's own words using the roots and affixes the language offers. The root pov- and the suffix -e to make an adverb are examples of that. So "pove" certainly could be a word.

An additional question might be whether it's a common word that people in Esperantujo already use sometimes. I think it's not that common—I can't remember having come across it before—but I'd certainly understand it if someone did use it, and I think that if you want to use it, you could do so with more or less the meaning you already gave for it (although perhaps it would be more likely used with a somewhat different meaning, see Neil Roberts's answer). Bear in mind, though, that other forms might be considered and might be more common, such as "plenpove" or "povhave" or some such.

As for its absence in PIV, the extreme productive freedom to make words in Esperanto means that any one dictionary, no matter how great a resource it might be, could never list all possible words in the language. So it could be an indication of the frequency of a word, and if it's in there obviously it (normally) gives a nice definition, but if it doesn't occur in PIV, that in and of itself does not mean it is not a word one could use in Esperanto.

---

ESPERANTO:

En Esperanto, oni estas libera mem fari vortojn laŭ la vortradikoj kaj la afiksoj. Tiu inkludas la vortradikon pov- kaj la sufikson -e por fari adverbon. Do certe "pove" povas esti vorto.

La kroma demando estas, ĉu ĝi estas ofta vorto, kiun oni jam uzas de tempo al tempo en Esperantujo. Laŭ mi, ĝi ne estas tre ofta—mi ne memoras vidi ĝin antaŭe—sed certe mi komprenus ĝin se oni ja uzus ĝin, kaj mi pensas, ke se vi volas, vi tute povas uzi ĝin kun pli-malpli tiu signifo, kiun vi mem jam donis (kvankam 'pove' oni uzus ĝin pli verŝajne kun iom alia signifo, rigardu do la respondon de pova Neil Roberts). Sed rimarku, ke oni povus konsideri aliajn formojn, kiuj eble estus pli oftaj, kiel "plenpove" aŭ "povhave", ekzemple.

Pri ĝia manko en PIV, notu, ke la ekstreme libereco fari novajn vortojn en Esperanto signifas, ke neniu vortaro, eĉ tre utilan kun vasta kolekto de difinoj, povus listigi ĉiujn eblajn vortojn en la lingvo. Do ĝi povas esti indikilo pri la ofteco de vorto, kaj se vorto ja enestas kompreneble la vortaro donus bonan signifon (kutime), sed se ne estas en PIV, tio ankoraŭ ne nepre signifas, ke ne estas vorto, kiun oni povus uzi en Esperanto.

Comment: Kiel respondo bonega! Ĝi respondas mian demandon, sed ankaû multajn aliajn demandojn, kiujn mi eble podus havi. Dankon!

Comment: Nedankinde! Dankon pro via laŭdo.

Answer (score 5):

La respondo de Vincent bone montras ke la vorto povas esti uzata. Tamen mi ne kredas ke ĝi havus similan signifon kiel *eble*. *Eble* signifas ke io povas okazi. Ekzemple:

> Eble Poutou estos la prezidanto de Francio.

Aliflanke mi kredas ke *pove* signifus ke io havas povon, ke ĝi povas ion. Ekzemple:

> Esti prezidanto estas pove.

T.e., esti prezidanto havas povon.

Tamen mi konsentas ke eble estus pli klare uzi alian vorton en tiu ekzemplo, kiel *povhave*.

Comment: Vi pravas, ke se oni uzus pove, verŝajne oni uzus ĝin kun la signifo, kiun ĝi havas en via ekzemplo. Mi iom redaktis mian respondon.